# Print last 10/20/... svn log messages with diffs

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

I am using SVN for a project. with `svn log -l 10`, I can get the last 10 commits to this folder, with the revision id, log message, etc.. Is there any SVN command that lets me print out on the command line all the diffs for each of those changesets? I'd like to do some grepping/etc. with the last X diffs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SVN v1.7, there are the

```
 --diff                   : produce diff output
 --diff-cmd ARG           : use ARG as diff command
```

options that you can use with `svn log`

For older version (which is probably your case), you will have to do some scripting to supply revision to `svn diff` and get the output

Comment: Cool! Not released yet, and not avaible on my ubuntu package manager, but good to know that it's coming.

Comment: @Rory - they are available here, but yeah pre-release. I am using 1.7. http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#pre-release

Answer (score 2):

For older svn, you can use function:

```
 svn-log-diff()
 {
        for c in `svn log "$@"  | grep '^r' | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed s/r/-c/`; do
             svn diff --force $c || break
        done
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - is there something wrong with the `sed` ?

Comment: It works. And I added another command inside the loop: `svn log -v $c`, so I can see commit messages AND diffs in the same place (but it's slow as it has to do a second lookup).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Linux, use the following script. save it like svn-diffs.sh.
Then run

```
sh svn-diffs.sh 10
```

This adds the diffed contents to files under a newly created diffs/ dir. That way, you can grep through without worrying about latency later on. This worked in my tests. 
You may grep through the files under diffs/ dir separately to have a colored output.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author - Kasun Gajasinghe
HEAD="HEAD"
limit=${1}
[[ -z "$1" ]] && limit=10

revisions=$(svn log -l $limit | grep -r "r[0-9][0-9]*\w" -o | grep -r "[0-9][0-9]*" -o)
mkdir diffs
echo $revisions > diffs/revisions.log

for revision in ${revisions}
do
#       svn diff -r $revision:${HEAD} } | grep -ri "SEARCHME" || exit 1

        diff=$(svn diff -r $revision:${HEAD})
        echo "$diff" > diffs/diffs-$revision-$HEAD.log
        echo "=======================" >> diffs/diffs-$revision-$HEAD.log
        HEAD=$revision
done

grep -ri "searchme" diffs/
```